# How to increase label's count by tapping on a button in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to increase a label's count by clicking on a button but the label is in child view controller.

[image: Here is the view controller and child view controller]

I want to increase label's(2) count by tapping on mark for review button(1).

I have declared a variable in a view controller as:

```
var value:Int = 0
```

Then on the button's IBAction I've done this:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender:UIButton){
    value = value + 1           
}
```

This is the code to access the child view controller:

```
var containerVc: UIViewController?

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: Any?){
    if segue.identifier == "identifier" {
        let childVc = segue.destination as! ChildVC
        childVc.label.text = "\(value)" // Unexpectedly found nil

    }
}
```

I am getting the error which I commented above.

Comment: Did you connect `label` from the `storyboard/xib` to `ViewController`?

Comment: @Kamran Yes, I did.

Comment: Where is your perform segue ?

Comment: @sekoyaz I used prepare method in view controller.

Comment: At the time of the segue, the outlets aren’t connected yet which is why it is nil.  Besides, you should never directly modify another VC’s outlets. Instead, pass your value to a property of the child VC, and then update the label in viewDidLoad in the child VC.

Comment: @vacawama I did that too still doesn't work. It doesn't show the value nil but also does nothing.

Comment: I declared this property: [var lbl:String = ""] in childVC and in viewDidLoad I updated the label as [label.text = lbl]. Then in VC I wrote this childVc.lbl = "\(value)".

Comment: What about the segue identifier i.e 'identifier' is it set correctly ?

Comment: @DebashishDas Yes